# Getting Next value from sequence with spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am using spring jpa repository with hibernate to save entites to my oracle database. How I can get the next value of my oracle database sequence using Spring-Hibernate?

This is my Event class :

```
@Entity
public class Event {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private Long seriesId;

  private String description;

  public Event() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Long getSeriesId() {
    return seriesId;
  }

  public void setSeriesId(Long seriesId) {
    this.seriesId = seriesId;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

I need to get the next value of the sequence once for the all event series in the event resolver.

```
public class EventResolver {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    public void createSeriesOfEvents(List<EventAPI> eventsToCreate){

        Long seriesId = null; // TODO: Get the series id from database sequence

        for (EventAPI currEvent : eventsToCreate){
            Event newEvent = new Event();
            newEvent.setDescription(currEvent.description);
            newEvent.setSeriesId(seriesId);
            eventRepository.save(newEvent);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help..

Comment: Why? Apply the correct annotation to the `@ID` field and Hibernate will do all this for you. See, for example:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequence_objects  http://tech.zooplus.com/sequences-in-hibernate/

Comment: I want the same value for the whole series (series can be 4-5 events) so I cant generate it when i create the `Event` entity. I must do it in the `createSeriesOfEvents` method

Comment: Spring 5 offers new options to tackle this problem. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56139316/7952453)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally I Solved my problem in the Spring way, All you need is to add a native query in the JpaRepository like this:

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT seq_name.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = 
        true)
 Long getNextSeriesId();
```

Comment: just have to make sure the query compliance for dependant database(s).

Comment: Won't that break the thing - meaning that we use an interface so Spring can make the implementation and we DON'T have to worry about which db is underlying..? In this case, to switch the db I'd have to rewrite the interface...

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c but this query is not returning nothing and causing NullPointerException

Comment: How to do it without using native query ? @Ron Badur, I am stuck at this beacuse I dont want to use native query.

Comment: Can you explain what is `Event` object in your code?

Comment: @aswzen Event is the object on which you are making the operation. the object you are going to query or save using this repository

Answer (score 6):

With Spring 5, you can use one of their built-in classes for this task like [OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/incrementer/OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.html)

See all the available options in this package: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/incrementer/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

Annotate your id property like so:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "idSequence")
@SequenceGenerator(schema = "MYORASCHEMA", name = "idSequence", sequenceName = "MY_ORACLE_SEQ_NAME", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;
```

Comment: I dont want that every object will get his own id , I want to give the same series id to all the series (4-5 objects of Event type)

Comment: Do you have a parent table for the series?

Comment: no I just want the option of creating a series of events - It means few events with the same series id but different id

Comment: This was a headache for me, so for others:  YOU NEED THE ALLOCATION SIZE.  Reason, see https://ntsim.uk/posts/how-to-use-hibernate-identifier-sequence-generators-properly.  Summary:  Hibernate uses hi-lo strategy to get id, so if the db sequence doesn't allocate in blocks of 50, it will interfere with previously provided ids and you will get constraint exception.

Comment: @Ron You can use the same generator for your issue.  Just use the same generator name, and declare it at class level.  You should be able to use it in other classes too (though I haven't confirmed this).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach in JPA:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select seq_name.nextval from dual");
return (Long)q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: from where I can get the `em` object?

Comment: `em` means EntityManager and you can autowire it