# oracle DB sequence with Spring Boot

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, sequence

I am using **spring boot**, and need a sequence variable, and decided to use DB sequence, And I want to get `nextval` from the sequence. HQL query `select nextval('db_seq_name') as num` is not working, I am looking for some other way. Please guide me.

> My Question is : How to get Nextval from a DB Sequence in Spring Boot with hibernate query language.

Comment: just use "select db_seq_name.nextval from dual"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Next value from sequence with spring hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240529/getting-next-value-from-sequence-with-spring-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not clear, I will make some wild guesses.

```
public interface NextValRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select nextval('db_seq_name')", nativeQuery = true)
    public Integer nextVal();

}
```

And @Autowired this anywhere you want to use next value from the sequence.

Comment: I dont want to create native query because it is database dependent, I want to use hibernate Query Language, please check my updated question